# How can I make git or pip bootstrap without errors?

Tags: git, pip, bootstrapper

When I'm trying to install from bootstrapper.txt

```
$ pip install -r bootstrapper.txt
```

Then I have the following traceback with error:

```
Downloading/unpacking python-keystoneclient==0.1.1 (from -r http://git.ged.ru/ged-thrift-server.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/requirements.txt (line 49))
    Downloading python-keystoneclient-0.1.1.tar.gz (54Kb): 54Kb downloaded
    Running setup.py egg_info for package python-keystoneclient

    warning: no files found matching 'python-keystoneclient'
Downloading/unpacking kazoo==0.2 (from -r http://git.ged.ru/ged-thrift-server.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/requirements.txt (line 50))
    Downloading kazoo-0.2.tar.gz (46Kb): 46Kb downloaded
    Running setup.py egg_info for package kazoo

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyo' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking Sphinx==1.1.3 (from -r http://git.ged.ru/ged-thrift-server.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/requirements.txt (line 53))
    Downloading Sphinx-1.1.3.tar.gz (2.6Mb): 2.6Mb downloaded
    Running setup.py egg_info for package Sphinx

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
Obtaining pylib from git+ssh://git@git.ged.ru/pylib.git@a1f66e8dc124165e89fc76dd6f2bf86ccd0527e7#egg=pylib-dev (from -r http://git.ged.ru/ged-thrift-server.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/requirements.txt (line 56))
    Cloning ssh://git@git.ged.ru/pylib.git (to a1f66e8dc124165e89fc76dd6f2bf86ccd0527e7) to ./src/pylib
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/git rev-parse origin/HEAD:
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

origin/HEAD

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/git rev-parse origin/HEAD failed with error code 128
Storing complete log in /home/ks/.pip/pip.log
```

http://dumpz.org/246888/ - this is traceback(from /home/ks/.pip/pip.log).

And my pip version is:

```
pip 1.0.2 from /home/ks/python/ged/converters/prosto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

UPD:

so, yet after I update it to 1.1 - it's make the same error..

What I should to do to solve this?

Comment: What is your `git` version? (Use `/usr/bin/git --version` to see)

Comment: 1.1 as I remember - I'm not on working machine now.

Comment: Maybe that is the problem. Update your git version and come back with more info, please. (git 1.1 was released about 7 years ago: https://github.com/git/git/tags?after=v1.4.2-rc3&curr=v1.5.6.6)

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks. May be. So I should to install it from repo,  and not via apt-get install(cause - this variant it's about 1.1 ver.).

Answer (score 2):

What is your git config setting for color.ui?

> git config --get color.ui

Mine was set to 'always', and I got this same error.

When I changed it to 'true',

> git config --global color.ui true

that fixed this error in my case.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Colors-in-Git

Comment: I solve the problem when I changed version of this one to newest. =)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already got this worked out, but for anyone else out there who might encounter this error, I had this same rev-parse problem when I was trying to pip install a remote git package at a specific commit head.

I was running pip 1.2.1.

When I updated pip to the most recent version (at this point, it's 1.5.6), that git rev-parse error went away.